# Foreign key of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

I have the following 3 tables:

```
╔═════════════════╗
║   Companies     ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ id              ║
║ name            ║
║ type            ║
║ etc...          ║
╚═════════════════╝
╔══════════════╗
║   Contacts   ║
╠══════════════╣
║ id           ║
║ company_id   ║
║ first_name   ║
║ last_name    ║
║ etc...       ║
╚══════════════╝
╔═══════════════╗
║   Addresses   ║
╠═══════════════╣
║ id            ║
║ foreign_key   ║
║ address_1     ║
║ address_2     ║
║ city          ║
║ state         ║
║ zip           ║
║ etc...        ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

My problem is that both Companies and Contacts can have multiple addresses associated with them. Their ID numbers might be overlapping. What would I store in the `foreign_key` column in the `addresses` table?

Comment: Normally there is no `foreign_key` column in a table.  Instead, you can add two separate columns with the names `company_id` and `contact_id` and store the respective ids in those.

Comment: @dezso - I know. The `foreign_key` column name was just an example to illustrate a point. Regarding your solution: if I then have another table that uses the `addresses` table, do I then add another column to the `addresses` table? When does this madness end?

Comment: Life is risky...

Answer (score 4):

You have couple options. I'd describe one I like the most, but you can find others searching for 'resolving polymorphic association in database'.  Add a common table for `companies` and `contacts` (I'd prefer to rename `contacts` to `people` or `persons`), say `party`. Thus, `companies` and `contacts` will have FK to `party`. Then you add link table `party_address(address_id,party_id)` with FKs to `addresses` and `party` respectively.

**UPDATE**
For instance (I know it's oversimplified, normally you may have different address_type, address change history, etc, but I guess it illustrates idea).

Note: enum is used because mysql still doesn't have check constraints. Unique constraint on (party_id, party_type) added so child tables can have a foreign key references to it; thus, optional relationship implemented and enforced on database level- Party can be either Person or Organization; no way it can be Person and Organization at the same time.

```
  CREATE TABLE PARTY (party_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
party_type enum('person','organization') not null,
CONSTRAINT UQ_PARTY UNIQUE(party_id,party_type));

CREATE TABLE PERSON (party_id int not null primary key, 
party_type enum('person') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'person',
....
CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_PARTY FOREIGN KEY(party_id,party_type) 
 REFERENCES PARTY(party_id,party_type));

CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATION (party_id int not null primary key, 
party_type enum('organization') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'organization',
....
CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_PARTY FOREIGN KEY(party_id,party_type) 
 REFERENCES PARTY(party_id,party_type));

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS(address_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
.... );

CREATE TABLE PARTY_ADDRESS (party_id INT NOT NULL, address_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PARTY_ADDRESS PRIMARY KEY(party_id,address_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_PARTY_ADDRESS_PARTY FOREIGN KEY (party_id) REFERENCES PARTY(party_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_PARTY_ADDRESS_ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES ADDRESS(address_id));
```

Comment: You have the makings of a good answer here. Would you be willing to script/diagram it out a bit more (using the example structure) for the OP since they seem to not have a conceptual understanding of relational data?

Comment: Example added, I hope it illustrates the idea of common parent approach.